# grep select only line with a : inside the value being extracted

Tags: bash

I want to automate some tasks for a project. For that, I need some parameters of a videofile. With mediainfo, I can print out all of the necessary informations I need. So I did this:

```
  mediainfo --fullscan "${OriginalVideoFile}" > "OriginalVideoFileInformations.txt";
```

And then, i tried to get some parameters I need with grep, like this for example. In the txt file this is the first line I get, when I grep for "Width":
Width                                    : 720

```
  Cache1=$(grep "Width" -m 1 "OriginalVideoFileInformations.txt");
  OriginalVideoWidth="${Cache1#Width*: }";
  echo "video width: ${OriginalVideoWidth} pixels";
```

So far, everything works great! But then, i want to get the display aspect ratio. In the OriginalVideoFileInromations.txt file are to lines written:

```
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.778
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
```

If I grep for "Display aspect ratio" I get both lines obviously. But I only need 16:9 in a variable stored. Is there a way to do this? I tried to use different parameters with grep, but really don't know how to do this. Please note, that i don't want the "second line". I want the line which contains 16:9. I can't insure that this parameter is always the second line every time i use mediainfo.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you want to search for a line with two colons in it, then? `grep -E 'aspect .*:.*:'`, then.

Comment: That said, "how do I grep for a line with two colons" is arguably what in the old days we would have closed as "too localized" (we don't want a new, separate question for every possible pattern "two dashes", "two commas", etc). I'm trying to think what a better formulation of this question might be.

Comment: (You could also, f/e, use `'aspect.*[[:digit:]]:[[:digit:]]'`, matching only a `:` that's between two numbers with the word `aspect` earlier in the same line)

Answer (score 4):

The `mediainfo` command provides some processing-friendly formatting template and structured output formats like XML or (undocumented while 100% functional JSON) to ease reading or parsing the media-info data one need.

It is not perfect, but still a more appropriate mean to extract data rather than parsing a display-oriented output; that can be unpredictable across environments and versions of the tool though.

```
       --Inform=FMT
           Template defined information display.

           FMT is "[xxx;]Text", where xxx can be any one of General, Video, Audio, Text,
           Chapter, Image, or Menu. Text can be the template text, or a filename in the
           form of file:///path

           See --Info-Parameters for available parameters in the text. Parameters must
           be surrounded by "%".

       --Info-Parameters
           Display list of --Inform parameters
```

For example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=$1

read -r videoWidth videoHeight videoAspectRatio < <(
    mediainfo --Inform=$'Video;%Width%\t%Height%\t%DisplayAspectRatio%' "$file"
)

printf 'Information about file %s\n\n' "$file"
printf 'Video width: %d\n' "$videoWidth"
printf 'Video height: %s\n' "$videoHeight"
LC_NUMERIC=C printf 'Video Aspect-Ratio: %0.3f\n' "$videoAspectRatio"
```

Or with a POSIX-shell grammar:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

file=$1

mkfifo /tmp/mediainfo.fifo

inform="Video;$(printf '%%%s%%\t' Width Height DisplayAspectRatio)"

mediainfo --Inform="$inform" "$file" > /tmp/mediainfo.fifo &

read -r videoWidth videoHeight videoAspectRatio < /tmp/mediainfo.fifo

printf 'Information about file %s\n\n' "$file"
printf 'Video width: %d\n' "$videoWidth"
printf 'Video height: %s\n' "$videoHeight"
LC_NUMERIC=C printf 'Video Aspect-Ratio: %0.3f\n' "$videoAspectRatio"

rm -f /tmp/mediainfo.fifo
```

Handling media info susceptible of containing special characters like `@ref`

The undocumented JSON output format may be a suitable format here to deal with such case:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=$1

{
  read -rd '' ref
  read -rd '' videoWidth
  read -rd '' videoHeight
  read -rd '' videoAspectRatio
} < <(
mediainfo --Output=JSON "$file" |
jq -j '
.media | [
    ."@ref"
  ] + (
  .track[] | select(."@type" == "Video") | [
    .Width,
    .Height,
    .DisplayAspectRatio
  ] )
 | .[] + "\u0000" 
'
)

printf 'Information about ref: %s\n\n' "$ref"
printf 'Video width: %d\n' "$videoWidth"
printf 'Video height: %s\n' "$videoHeight"
LC_NUMERIC=C printf 'Video Aspect-Ratio: %0.3f\n' "$videoAspectRatio"
```

Output I get from one of my video files named `2021-08-17 14-23-48.mp4` (with a space in it, could be  newlines or a tabulation or whatever):

```
Information about ref: 2021-08-17 14-23-48.mp4

Video width: 1280
Video height: 720
Video Aspect-Ratio: 1.778
```

Comment: Couldn't the FIFO voodoo be avoided with something simpler, like `set - $(mediainfo --Inform="$inform" "$file")`?

Comment: @tripleee it could work as long as media info data does not contains spaces. It'd be equally voodoo IMHO. If one has data with newline that would be even trickier (while still possible).

Comment: Yeah, in the general case you'd have to cope with free-form tags; but the OP's expected output is just simple numbers with some punctuation. Or you could run one query at a time and assign the output of each to a separate variable.

Comment: @tripleee I had to use undocumented JSON output and jq because, unfortunately `--Inform` has no support for adding a null character between values. It did not had support for tab escaping like `\t` and required raw tab code. It would have made streaming values to shell much less like black magic if its `--Inform` had support for escaping non-printable characters, including `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ DisplayAspectRatio=$( awk '/Display aspect ratio/ && ($NF ~ /:/) { print $NF }' file )
$ echo "$DisplayAspectRatio"
16:9
```